# how to update database colum with checkbox in gridview vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i have a checkbox in gridview rows...and have a database column name "Active" whose default value is "1"

i bind checkbox with database colum active...

when i click on checkbox by default its is checked because the default value of active in dbase column is 1 ..

I want when i uncheck checkbox the value updated on active column of selected row will be 0...and checkbox remains unchecked....

I have a code sippet but not working

```
 Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            'Find the checkbox
            Dim Chk1 As CheckBox = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
            Dim id As HiddenField = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
            Dim active As HiddenField = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("HiddenField3"), HiddenField)
            Dim SQLData As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=clixngo")
            Dim cmdSelect As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM my_state where id='" & id.Value & "'", SQLData)
            SQLData.Open()
            Dim dtrReader As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader()
            If dtrReader.HasRows Then
                While dtrReader.Read()
                    Chk1.Checked = dtrReader("active")
                End While
            Else
            End If
            dtrReader.Close()
            SQLData.Close()

        Next
    End Sub

    Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        For Each myRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim Chk1 As CheckBox = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
            Dim id As HiddenField = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)
            Dim active As HiddenField = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("HiddenField3"), HiddenField)
            If Chk1.Checked = True Then
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("id").DefaultValue = id.Value
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("active").DefaultValue = "1"
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("state").DefaultValue = "Andaman and Nicobar"
                SqlDataSource1.Update()
            ElseIf Chk1.Checked = False Then
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("id").DefaultValue = id.Value
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("active").DefaultValue = "0"
                SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("state").DefaultValue = "Andaman and Nicobar"
                SqlDataSource1.Update()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Database updation is not happening or unchecking tick is not appearing?

Comment: Yes...But i did it my self

Comment: oh good.So,what's the mistake you have done and how it resolved.